# Array of Objects not inizializing new Object when add element to array

Tags: java, arrays, object

The array is initialized in the correct position and everything else looks good. I just cannot figure out why when I print the finished array it makes all elements identical.

When I debugged it it stores the new element a new location on the array but it does not create a new instance of that object.

Array initialization:

```
public class CalcFrame implements ActionListener
{
   private static Calculation[] calc_array = new Calculation[10];
```

on action...

```
if(ae.getSource() == calc_answer_position)
{ 
      calc_array[count] = new Calculation();
      calc_array[count].setIntVel(Double.parseDouble(init_vel_tf.getText())); 
      calc_array[count].setIntPos(Double.parseDouble(init_pos_tf.getText()));
      calc_array[count].setAccel(Double.parseDouble(acc_tf.getText()));
      calc_array[count].setTime(Double.parseDouble(time_tf.getText()));


      double ans = getArray(count).calcPosition(getArray(count).getIntVel(),
                   getArray(count).getIntPos(), getArray(count).getAccel(),
                    getArray(count).getTime());
      count++;

      int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Position x(t) = " + ans,
              "Answer: Calculate Position", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

      if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
      {
          frame.dispose();
      }
          if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
      {
          System.exit(0);
      } 
}
```

Calculation class....EDIT

```
public class Calculation 
{
   //These are the attributes for the Variables object.
   private static double initial_accel = 0.0,
                                 initial_velocity = 0.0,
                                 initial_position = 0.0,
                                 acceleration = 0.0,
                                 velocity = 0.0,
                                 position = 0.0,
                                 time = 0.0,
                                 height = 0.0,
                                 mass = 0.0,
                                 weight = 0.0,
                                 answer = 0.0;


    public Calculation() {}

    public Calculation(double initial_velocity, double initial_position, double acceleration, double time)
    {
        setIntVel(initial_velocity);
        setIntPos(initial_position);
        setAccel(acceleration);
        setTime(time);
    }

    public Calculation(double initial_velocity, double initial_position, double acceleration, double time, double position)
    {
        setIntVel(initial_velocity);
        setIntPos(initial_position);
        setAccel(acceleration);
        setPos(position);
        setTime(0);
    }

    public static double calcPosition(double in_vel, double in_pos, double acc, double time)
    {
       //x(t) = xi + vi(t) + .5(a)t^2

        double answer = .5 * time * time * acc;
        answer = (in_pos + (in_vel * time) + answer);
       return answer;
    }

    public static double calcTime(double in_vel, double in_pos, double acc, double pos)                 
    {
       //t = (-vi + sqrt(vi^2 - 2(a)xi)) / a

        double answer = (in_vel * in_vel) - (2 * acc * (in_pos - pos));
      answer = ((-1 * in_vel) + Math.sqrt(answer)) / (acc);
       return answer;
    }

    //===MUTATORS===//

    public void setIntAccel(double initial_accel) 
    {
       this.initial_accel = initial_accel;
    }

    public void setIntVel(double initial_velocity) 
    {
       this.initial_velocity = initial_velocity;
    }

    public void setIntPos(double initial_position) 
    {
       this.initial_position = initial_position;
    }

    public void setAccel(double acceleration) 
    {
       this.acceleration = acceleration;
    }

    public void setVel(double velocity) 
    {
       this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public void setPos(double position) 
    {
       this.position = position;
    }

    public void setTime(double time) 
    {
       this.time = time;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) 
    {
       this.height = height;
    }

    public void setMass(double mass) 
    {
       this.mass = mass;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) 
    {
       this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setAnswer(double answer) 
    {
       this.answer = answer;
    }


    //===ACCESSORS===//

    public double getIntAccel()
    {
       return initial_accel;
    }

    public double getIntVel() 
    {
       return initial_velocity;
    }

    public double getIntPos() 
    {
       return initial_position;
    }

    public double getAccel()
    {
       return acceleration;
    }

    public double getVel()
    {
       return velocity;
    }

    public double getPos()
    {
       return position;
    }

    public double getTime()
    {
       return time;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
       return height;
    }

    public double getMass()
    {
       return mass;
    }

    public double getWeight() 
    {
       return weight;
    }

    public double getAnswer() 
    {
       return answer;
    }

    public String toString()
    {

        String result = "Initial Position: " + getIntPos();
        result += "\nAcceleration: " + getAccel();
        result += "\nInitial Velocity: " + getIntVel();
        result += "\nPosition: " + getPos();
        result += "\nTime: " + getTime();
        return result;
    }


}
```

CalcFrame class ... EDIT

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CalcFrame implements ActionListener
{
   private static Calculation[] calc_array = new Calculation[10];  

    private JLabel init_vel_label,
                   init_pos_label,
                        acc_label,
                        time_label,
                        pos_label;

    private JButton calc_answer_time,
                    calc_answer_position;

    private static JFrame frame;

    private JTextField init_vel_tf,
                       init_pos_tf,
                             acc_tf,
                             time_tf,
                             pos_tf;

    private static int count = 0;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up the main GUI components.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public CalcFrame(int operation)
   {
      if(operation == 2)
           CalcTime();
        if(operation == 1)
           CalcPosition();
   }

    public void CalcTime()
   {
      frame = new JFrame ("Quadratic Calculator");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
       Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();

        init_vel_label = new JLabel ("Initial Velocity");
        init_pos_label = new JLabel ("Initial Position");
        acc_label = new JLabel ("Acceleration");
        pos_label = new JLabel ("Position at time (t)");

        //textfields
      init_vel_tf = new JTextField (10);
        init_pos_tf = new JTextField (10);
        acc_tf = new JTextField (10);
        pos_tf = new JTextField (10);

        //button
        calc_answer_time = new JButton("Calculate");
      calc_answer_time.addActionListener(this);


      frame.add (init_vel_label);
        frame.add (init_vel_tf);
        frame.add (init_pos_label);
        frame.add (init_pos_tf);
        frame.add (acc_label);
        frame.add (acc_tf);
        frame.add (pos_label);
        frame.add (pos_tf);
        frame.add (calc_answer_time);


        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 275));
      frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocation((d.width/2)-380, (d.height/2)-200);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setBackground (new Color(0,0,156));
        frame.getContentPane();
   }

    public void CalcPosition()
   {
      frame = new JFrame ("Quadratic Calculator");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
       Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();

        init_vel_label = new JLabel ("Initial Velocity");
        init_pos_label = new JLabel ("Initial Position");
        acc_label = new JLabel ("Acceleration");
        time_label = new JLabel ("Time (or change in time)");

        //textfields
      init_vel_tf = new JTextField (10);
        init_pos_tf = new JTextField (10);
        acc_tf = new JTextField (10);
        time_tf = new JTextField (10);

        //button
        calc_answer_position = new JButton("Calculate");
      calc_answer_position.addActionListener(this);


      frame.add (init_vel_label);
        frame.add (init_vel_tf);
        frame.add (init_pos_label);
        frame.add (init_pos_tf);
        frame.add (acc_label);
        frame.add (acc_tf);
        frame.add (time_label);
        frame.add (time_tf);
        frame.add (calc_answer_position);


        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 275));
      frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocation((d.width/2)-380, (d.height/2)-200);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setBackground (new Color(0,0,156));
        frame.getContentPane();
   }

    public static void sort()
    {
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0;
         Calculation k;
         for(i = getSize() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
             for(j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)
              {
                  if(getArray(j).getIntVel() > getArray(j + 1).getIntVel())
                    {
                        k = getArray(j);
                         setArray(j, getArray(j + 1));
                         setArray(j + 1, k);
                    }
              }
         }
    }

    public static Calculation getArray(int i)
    {
       return calc_array[i];
    }

    public static Calculation[] getEntireArray()
    {
       return calc_array;
    }

    public static void setArray(int i, Calculation c)
    {
       calc_array[i] = c;
    }

    public static int getSize()
    {
       return count;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    { 
          Object[] options = {"Main Menu",
                                "Exit"};

      if(ae.getSource() == calc_answer_position)
      { 
         calc_array[count] = new Calculation();
          calc_array[count].setIntVel(Double.parseDouble(init_vel_tf.getText())); 
          calc_array[count].setIntPos(Double.parseDouble(init_pos_tf.getText()));
          calc_array[count].setAccel(Double.parseDouble(acc_tf.getText()));
          calc_array[count].setTime(Double.parseDouble(time_tf.getText()));


          double ans = getArray(count).calcPosition(getArray(count).getIntVel(),
                       getArray(count).getIntPos(), getArray(count).getAccel(),
                        getArray(count).getTime());
          count++;

          int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Position x(t) = " + ans,
                  "Answer: Calculate Position", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                     if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                     {
                         frame.dispose();
                     }
                     if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                     {
                         System.exit(0);
                     }


        }

          if(ae.getSource() == calc_answer_time)
          { 

              calc_array[count] = new Calculation(Double.parseDouble(init_vel_tf.getText()), 
                       Double.parseDouble(init_pos_tf.getText()), Double.parseDouble(acc_tf.getText()),
                          0, Double.parseDouble(pos_tf.getText()));


              double ans = getArray(count).calcTime(getArray(count).getIntVel(), getArray(count).getIntPos(), getArray(count).getAccel(), getArray(count).getPos());
              count++;

              int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Time t = " + ans, "Answer: Calculate Time", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                         if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                         {
                             frame.dispose();
                         }
                         if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                         {
                             System.exit(0);
                         }


          }

   }
}
```

I think that is all that is needed for the question, please let me know if you need more information, I will be standing by.

Thank you again

**UPDATED CODE FOLLOWS....**

The only fixes made are the removal of the static keywords in the Calculation class and the change of the call to the array.

example:

```
getArray(j).getIntVel() changed to ... calc_array[j].getIntVel()
```

Calculation class updated...

```
public class Calculation 
{
   //These are the attributes for the Variables object.
   private double initial_accel = 0.0,
                                 initial_velocity = 0.0,
                                 initial_position = 0.0,
                                 acceleration = 0.0,
                                 velocity = 0.0,
                                 position = 0.0,
                                 time = 0.0,
                                 height = 0.0,
                                 mass = 0.0,
                                 weight = 0.0,
                                 answer = 0.0;


    public Calculation() {}

    public Calculation(double initial_velocity, double initial_position, double acceleration, double time)
    {
        setIntVel(initial_velocity);
        setIntPos(initial_position);
        setAccel(acceleration);
        setTime(time);
    }

    public Calculation(double initial_velocity, double initial_position, double acceleration, double time, double position)
    {
        setIntVel(initial_velocity);
        setIntPos(initial_position);
        setAccel(acceleration);
        setPos(position);
        setTime(0);
    }

    public double calcPosition(double in_vel, double in_pos, double acc, double time)
    {
       //x(t) = xi + vi(t) + .5(a)t^2

        double answer = .5 * time * time * acc;
        answer = (in_pos + (in_vel * time) + answer);
       return answer;
    }

    public double calcTime(double in_vel, double in_pos, double acc, double pos)                    
    {
       //t = (-vi + sqrt(vi^2 - 2(a)xi)) / a

        double answer = (in_vel * in_vel) - (2 * acc * (in_pos - pos));
      answer = ((-1 * in_vel) + Math.sqrt(answer)) / (acc);
       return answer;
    }

    //===MUTATORS===//

    public void setIntAccel(double initial_accel) 
    {
       this.initial_accel = initial_accel;
    }

    public void setIntVel(double initial_velocity) 
    {
       this.initial_velocity = initial_velocity;
    }

    public void setIntPos(double initial_position) 
    {
       this.initial_position = initial_position;
    }

    public void setAccel(double acceleration) 
    {
       this.acceleration = acceleration;
    }

    public void setVel(double velocity) 
    {
       this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public void setPos(double position) 
    {
       this.position = position;
    }

    public void setTime(double time) 
    {
       this.time = time;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) 
    {
       this.height = height;
    }

    public void setMass(double mass) 
    {
       this.mass = mass;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) 
    {
       this.weight = weight;
    }

    public void setAnswer(double answer) 
    {
       this.answer = answer;
    }


    //===ACCESSORS===//

    public double getIntAccel()
    {
       return initial_accel;
    }

    public double getIntVel() 
    {
       return initial_velocity;
    }

    public double getIntPos() 
    {
       return initial_position;
    }

    public double getAccel()
    {
       return acceleration;
    }

    public double getVel()
    {
       return velocity;
    }

    public double getPos()
    {
       return position;
    }

    public double getTime()
    {
       return time;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
       return height;
    }

    public double getMass()
    {
       return mass;
    }

    public double getWeight() 
    {
       return weight;
    }

    public double getAnswer() 
    {
       return answer;
    }

    public String toString()
    {

        String result = "Initial Position: " + getIntPos();
        result += "\nAcceleration: " + getAccel();
        result += "\nInitial Velocity: " + getIntVel();
        result += "\nPosition: " + getPos();
        result += "\nTime: " + getTime();
        return result;
    }


}
```

CalcFrame class updated...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CalcFrame implements ActionListener
{
   private static Calculation[] calc_array = new Calculation[10];  

    private JLabel init_vel_label,
                   init_pos_label,
                        acc_label,
                        time_label,
                        pos_label;

    private JButton calc_answer_time,
                    calc_answer_position;

    private static JFrame frame;

    private JTextField init_vel_tf,
                       init_pos_tf,
                             acc_tf,
                             time_tf,
                             pos_tf;

    private static int count = 0;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up the main GUI components.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public CalcFrame(int operation)
   {
      if(operation == 2)
           CalcTime();
        if(operation == 1)
           CalcPosition();
   }

    public void CalcTime()
   {
      frame = new JFrame ("Quadratic Calculator");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
       Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();

        init_vel_label = new JLabel ("Initial Velocity");
        init_pos_label = new JLabel ("Initial Position");
        acc_label = new JLabel ("Acceleration");
        pos_label = new JLabel ("Position at time (t)");

        //textfields
      init_vel_tf = new JTextField (10);
        init_pos_tf = new JTextField (10);
        acc_tf = new JTextField (10);
        pos_tf = new JTextField (10);

        //button
        calc_answer_time = new JButton("Calculate");
      calc_answer_time.addActionListener(this);


      frame.add (init_vel_label);
        frame.add (init_vel_tf);
        frame.add (init_pos_label);
        frame.add (init_pos_tf);
        frame.add (acc_label);
        frame.add (acc_tf);
        frame.add (pos_label);
        frame.add (pos_tf);
        frame.add (calc_answer_time);


        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 275));
      frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocation((d.width/2)-380, (d.height/2)-200);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setBackground (new Color(0,0,156));
        frame.getContentPane();
   }

    public void CalcPosition()
   {
      frame = new JFrame ("Quadratic Calculator");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
       Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();

        init_vel_label = new JLabel ("Initial Velocity");
        init_pos_label = new JLabel ("Initial Position");
        acc_label = new JLabel ("Acceleration");
        time_label = new JLabel ("Time (or change in time)");

        //textfields
      init_vel_tf = new JTextField (10);
        init_pos_tf = new JTextField (10);
        acc_tf = new JTextField (10);
        time_tf = new JTextField (10);

        //button
        calc_answer_position = new JButton("Calculate");
      calc_answer_position.addActionListener(this);


      frame.add (init_vel_label);
        frame.add (init_vel_tf);
        frame.add (init_pos_label);
        frame.add (init_pos_tf);
        frame.add (acc_label);
        frame.add (acc_tf);
        frame.add (time_label);
        frame.add (time_tf);
        frame.add (calc_answer_position);


        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 275));
      frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocation((d.width/2)-380, (d.height/2)-200);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setBackground (new Color(0,0,156));
        frame.getContentPane();
   }

    public static void sort()
    {
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0;
         Calculation k;
         for(i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
             for(j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)
              {
                  if(calc_array[j].getIntVel() > calc_array[j+1].getIntVel())
                    {
                        k = calc_array[j];
                         calc_array[j] = calc_array[j+1];
                         calc_array[j + 1] = k;
                    }
              }
         }
    }

    public static Calculation getArray(int i)
    {
       return calc_array[i];
    }

    public Calculation[] getEntireArray()
    {
       return calc_array;
    }

    public void setArray(int i, Calculation c)
    {
       calc_array[i] = c;
    }

    public static int getSize()
    {
       return count;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    { 
          Object[] options = {"Main Menu",
                                "Exit"};

      if(ae.getSource() == calc_answer_position)
      { 
         calc_array[count] = new Calculation();
          calc_array[count].setIntVel(Double.parseDouble(init_vel_tf.getText())); 
          calc_array[count].setIntPos(Double.parseDouble(init_pos_tf.getText()));
          calc_array[count].setAccel(Double.parseDouble(acc_tf.getText()));
          calc_array[count].setTime(Double.parseDouble(time_tf.getText()));


          double ans = getArray(count).calcPosition(getArray(count).getIntVel(),
                       getArray(count).getIntPos(), getArray(count).getAccel(),
                        getArray(count).getTime());
          count++;

          int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Position x(t) = " + ans,
                  "Answer: Calculate Position", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                     if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                     {
                         frame.dispose();
                     }
                     if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                     {
                         System.exit(0);
                     }


        }

          if(ae.getSource() == calc_answer_time)
          { 

              calc_array[count] = new Calculation(Double.parseDouble(init_vel_tf.getText()), 
                       Double.parseDouble(init_pos_tf.getText()), Double.parseDouble(acc_tf.getText()),
                          0, Double.parseDouble(pos_tf.getText()));


              double ans = getArray(count).calcTime(getArray(count).getIntVel(), getArray(count).getIntPos(), getArray(count).getAccel(), getArray(count).getPos());
              count++;

              int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Time t = " + ans, "Answer: Calculate Time", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

                         if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                         {
                             frame.dispose();
                         }
                         if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                         {
                             System.exit(0);
                         }


          }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you provide Calculation class? it could be a static issue

---

EDIT:

ok try removing static in your variable declaration

there

```
//These are the attributes for the Variables object.
   private **static** double initial_accel = 0.0,
```

also you will have to remove static on all the methods that those variables appear

think that the statics variables and/or methods are stand alone and they have no dependency on the current instance, which means that any static attribute will always be the same between objects of the same instance, you can even reefer to those attributes without instance

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.name = "User";
Person person2 = new Person()
person2.name = "Admin";
```

if name is static then person1.name will always be person2.name, otherwise they will have their own name

Comment: @CommonKnowledge: make sure you update your question with the updated code following this edit.

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling the method sort() anywhere in the code. Because i am seeing the below inside sort method

```
setArray(j, getArray(j + 1));
setArray(j + 1, k);
```

Since for  `Calculation k;` you are assigning a reference from the array through `getArray(int i)` method. Since you are playing with reference something might happen here. Its just a guess.